# How to do longitudinal analysis for 2x2x2 design in R?

Tags: r, time-series, lme4, longitudinal

I have a dataset with the following variables for the treatment (nutrition, fertilizer), that records algal growth in water across time (t0, t1...t10). In series with fertilizer marked as "nitrogen" , nitrogen was added after day t5. In series marked as "none", no nitrogen was added.

```
nutrition <- c("good","good","bad","bad","good","good","bad","bad","good","good","bad","bad","good","good","bad","bad")

fertlizer <- c("none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen","none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen","none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen","none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen")

t0 <- c(7,  6,  3, 20, 13,  4, 14,  9, 15,  5, 18, 19,  8,  1, 10, 16)
t1 <- c(12,  9,  3, 20,  4,  7,  6, 17, 19,  5, 18,  8, 15, 16, 10,  2)
t2 <- c(12,  9,  3, 20,  4,  7,  6, 17,7,  6,  3, 20, 13,  4, 14,  9)
t3 <- c(15,  5, 18, 19,  8,  1, 10, 16,4,  7,  6, 17,7,  6,  3, 20)
t4 <- c(6,7,12,4,7,18,9,10,2,10,11,14,15,1,14,16)
t5 <- c(4,  7,  6, 17,7,  6,  3, 20,15,  5, 18, 19,  8,  1, 10, 16)
t6 <- c(70,5,16,31,61,14,22,23,80,13,24,32,90,16,28,29)
t7 <- c(56,16,7,8,78,26,28,30,91,5,8,19,67,16,18,19)
t8 <- c(88,21,20,19,90,16,18,19,57,3, 20,  4,  7,67,13,12)
t9 <- c(62,12,15,27,71,20,  4,  7,72,6,  3, 20,73,14,  9, 15)
t10 <- c(40,13,7,19,50,3, 20, 7,66,14,  9, 15,80,16,18,19)


replicates <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)

data <- data.frame(nutrition, fertlizer,replicates, t0,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10)

data$nutrition <- as.factor(data$nutrition)
data$fertlizer <- as.factor(data$fertlizer)
```

I want to compare the slopes between groups and see if the slopes change after the fertilizer intervention. I want to use no fertilizer as control (i.e. (good, none) or (bad, none) as controls)

I transform this data into long format with column headers as "nutrition", "fertilizer", "time", "replicates", and "growth"
I create a new column called addition to distinguish between time periods before t5 and after t5. Time before t5 -> 0, after t5 ->1

```
   nutrition fertilizer time replicate growth addition
   good      none      t0   1         6        0
   good      none      t1   1         7        0
   ..
   ..
   good      none      t5   1         3        1
```

I run the following longitudinal analysis, with each column having the following structure:

```
nutrition: factor with 2 levels
fertlizer: factor with2 levels
time: factor with 10 levels
replicates: num 0,1,2,3...
growth: num 6, 7, 5 ...
addition: factor with 2 levels
```

lmer(growth ~ nutrition + fertlizer + time + addition + (1|replicates))

I get an errror message saying that fixed effects model is rank deficient so dropping x number of columns. Is there anyway around this problem? Are there suggestions to improve the way the model is written?

Comment: May be `lme` model from `nlme` package can help you.

Comment: Can you elucidate further?

Comment: you can't include both `time` and `addition` as fixed effects, because these sets of dummy variables are collinear.   You could try `lmer(value ~ nutr * fert * addition + (1 | id) + (1|time), dtf.long)`

Comment: Is id = replicates here? Why would time be a random effect? Would it be a factor or a numeric?

Comment: My model is still rank deficient using the model you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe it should get you somewhere in the ballpark.

```
dtf <- structure(list(nutr = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("bad", "good"
), class = "factor"), fert = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("N", 
"0"), class = "factor"), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), t0 = c(7, 6, 3, 20, 13, 4, 14, 9, 
15, 5, 18, 19, 8, 1, 10, 16), t1 = c(12, 9, 3, 20, 4, 7, 6, 17, 
19, 5, 18, 8, 15, 16, 10, 2), t2 = c(12, 9, 3, 20, 4, 7, 6, 17, 
7, 6, 3, 20, 13, 4, 14, 9), t3 = c(15, 5, 18, 19, 8, 1, 10, 16, 
4, 7, 6, 17, 7, 6, 3, 20), t4 = c(6, 7, 12, 4, 7, 18, 9, 10, 
2, 10, 11, 14, 15, 1, 14, 16), t5 = c(4, 7, 6, 17, 7, 6, 3, 20, 
15, 5, 18, 19, 8, 1, 10, 16), t6 = c(70, 5, 16, 31, 61, 14, 22, 
23, 80, 13, 24, 32, 90, 16, 28, 29), t7 = c(56, 16, 7, 8, 78, 
26, 28, 30, 91, 5, 8, 19, 67, 16, 18, 19), t8 = c(88, 21, 20, 
19, 90, 16, 18, 19, 57, 3, 20, 4, 7, 67, 13, 12), t9 = c(62, 
12, 15, 27, 71, 20, 4, 7, 72, 6, 3, 20, 73, 14, 9, 15), t10 = c(40, 
13, 7, 19, 50, 3, 20, 7, 66, 14, 9, 15, 80, 16, 18, 19)), .Names = c("nutr", 
"fert", "id", "t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", 
"t8", "t9", "t10"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

# Need to reshape into long format so that each column is a separate variable
library(reshape2)

dtf.long <- reshape2::melt(dtf, id.vars=1:3, variable.name="time")
dtf.long$time <- as.integer(sub("t", "", dtf.long$time))
dtf.long$fert2 <- dtf.long$time > 5 & dtf.long$fert == "N"

library(lattice)
xyplot(value ~ time | nutr * fert, data=dtf.long )

library(lme4)
m1.1 <- lmer(value ~ nutr * fert2 * time + (1 | id), dtf.long, REML=FALSE)
m1.2 <- lmer(value ~ nutr * fert2 * time + (1 + time | id), dtf.long, REML=FALSE)

# The random slope term doesn't appear to be adding anything of value
anova(m1.1, m1.2)
```

[These slides](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/slides/2011-03-16-Amsterdam/2Longitudinal.pdf) on longitudinal modelling in `lme4` might be of use.

Comment: Why is `addition` not included?

Comment: As Ben says, it's collinear, i.e. it adds no new information, i.e. it is an exact linear combination of other variables, i.e. it causes rank deficiency in the design matrix.

Comment: Also, my problem still does not go away. In my original data set each such treatment has 4 replicates and I have 26 columns for time

Comment: However, it gives me information about if the mean growth changed after day 5 or not. I have no indication now if there was a change in the fertilizer treatments after day 5.

Comment: Even if I use your model (m1) my problem still does not go away. In my original data set each such treatment has 4 replicates and I have 26 columns for time

Comment: Could you post some more of your data? Maybe not all 26 sample points, but all replicates would be nice.

Comment: I wonder if this is more a question for CrossValidated. If you do post the question there be sure to explain exactly what you want to learn from your data, it is'n quite clear here. Do you want to compare means before/after intervention? Do you want to compare change in mean between groups? Do you want to compare slopes between groups? Do you want to know if there is a significant change in slope after intervention? Do you want to use no fertilization as control, or do you want to compare between all four groups?

Comment: I did post this on cross validated but there was no clear answer. The model that I posted was after some debate with my colleagues. I have edited the answer in reply to your query. I want to compare the slopes between groups and see if the slopes change significantly after intervention. I want to use no fertilizer as control.

Comment: Comparing slopes is what we're doing now. Detecting a change in slope should also be doable, but I need some proper data.

Comment: That is what I had discerned when I started this analysis. I have updated the answer to depict my data.

Comment: Great! I know this is a  stretch, but can I ask why time is treated as a numeric rather than a factor in your analysis? When I use time as a factor I get a rank deficit in my analysis

Comment: Not entirely sure why I did what I did, but you were talking about longitudinal and slope, which suggests a numeric time variable to me. The before/after intervention factor component is added by `fert2`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, that error message means your predictors don't have enough information for your desired model to run. Perhaps you should consider using an ANOVA  or ANCOVA with a block? It would be totally fine to go this route considering the experimental nature of your data. You should also create a new column with your treatment groups. For example good nutrition w/ fertilizer, good nutrition w/o fertilizer can be called `GWF` and `GWOF`, same goes with the bad nutrition combos. This would give you 4 treatments and your block could be "time".

Posting a sample of your dataset would help in solving your problem

Comment: Using treatment groups does not solve the problem. In my original dataset, I have around 25 such time points and it would be rather large to post it on this forum. Any other suggestions?